# Add next estimated value to row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and trying to calculate an (estimated) value for the next cell in each row.

For example, I have the values: 2.1, 5.3, 8.5, 13.7 and want to estimate the next value in the sequence.

The sequence has no pattern and could be increasing or decreasing but will never be a negative number, so it could be: 10,9,8,7,6 etc. (but never -1).

Its possible that the sequence will have values greater and less than the previous number, like: 2, 4, 8, 5, 2, 6.

I have not linked any code examples because I'm in a right mess! If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be most grateful.

Thank you

Comment: It seems you want to fit a model into your data to find the next values(something like plotting the data and trying to mathematically/visually predict where the next value is goning to be), you should read about [polynomial fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could provide an example DataFrame, but it seems to me like what you're looking for is an autoregressive model.

A decent example is [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/autoregression-models-time-series-forecasting-python/).

Comment: Thanks for this Brad, I used the Persistence Model example in the link you provided and have also made use of [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) scipy to (hopefully) again accuracy. We will see!